# Java while function only evey 1 second

Tags: java, while-loop, bukkit

I have a while function. When it is true I want to proceed it only every 1 second. I can't use `Thread.sleep()`, because I am making Minecraft plugin and it will stop all processes on the server. Is there another way how to do it?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Why dont you run the while function in a new thread itself

Comment: you can add a daemon thread.

Comment: As an alternative to a new thread you could schedule a timer task to run at regular 1 second intervals (provided it doesn't take longer than 1 second to complete).

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the `Bukkit Scheduler`. It is integrated into the default plugin API and can be used to solve your task as following:

```
int taskID = Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do stuff
    }
}, delay, repeat);
```

Set the `delay` to 0 and the repeat to `20` (20 Ticks are 1 second).

Stop it by using:

```
Bukkit.getScheduler().cancelTask(taskID);
```

Comment: How can I use it in my code: https://pastebin.com/pZtYRmKi. I am trying to add 1 to a variable every second when you sneaking on Gold Block. I tried something with your code but it didn't work.

Comment: @TomášSoušek Solved?

Comment: I did it differently

Comment: Then go ahead and post your solution.

Comment: It is very unprofessional, but I did it with repeat command block.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a java.util.TimerTask
which can schedule your task after a specified time delay .
more details here : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-timertask-class-java/

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Thread.sleep()` in the main `Thread` you will block the `main thread` and for avoid this you need to create a separate thread pass to then the values you will need for process whatever you want in your thread, some snippet code for clarification:

```
public static boolean ENABLE_THREAD = true;

public static void main(String args[]){
    InnerThread minecraftThread = (new ThreadStack()).new InnerThread();
    minecraftThread.run();
}


public class InnerThread implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int counter=0;
        while(ENABLE_THREAD){
            try {
                //YOUR CODE
                System.out.println(counter);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                counter++;
                if(counter>10){
                    ENABLE_THREAD = false;
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `System.currentTimeMillis()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //The while(true) is to keep the next while loop running, otherwise, in 
    //this example, the condition System.currentTimeMillis()-past>=1000 
    //won't be true
    //It can be changed according to the needs

    long past = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(true)
    while(System.currentTimeMillis()-past>=1000) 
    {
        /*
         *DO what you need to do     
         */
        past = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the simplest solution I can think of. Please check if it works for you.

```
long start = new Date().getTime();

    while(new Date().getTime() - start < 1000L)
    {
    //Do Something every 1sec
    //you need to update the start value everytime
    start = new Date().getTime();
    }
```